# How to achieve this layout when pulling from a cms?

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, reactjs, content-management-system

I have this blog post layout which I need to create, but it requires featured posts and reversing of the flex container, how would I achieve this if the list of posts is being pulled from an API using Array.map()

I know how to map the post list if they have a uniform layout or a first post being different but how would I achieve every third post having a different layout compared to the normal post layout?

I am using React

Image: [image: Blog List Layout]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out I can target multiples of 3 using `.class:nth-child(3)` in order to change the stylings of every third post

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution to this question? I'd be happy to solve it.